# UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1]))

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have this code:

```
    actual_loes_score_g = actual_loes_score_t.to(self.device, non_blocking=True)

    predicted_loes_score_g = self.model(input_g)

    loss_func = nn.L1Loss()
    loss_g = loss_func(
        predicted_loes_score_g,
        actual_loes_score_g,
    )
```

where `predicted_loes_score_g` is `tensor([[-24.9374]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)` and `actual_loes_score_g` is `tensor([20.], dtype=torch.float64)`.  (I am using a batch size of 1 for debugging purposes.)

I am getting this warning:

```
torch/nn/modules/loss.py:96: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is 
different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect 
results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

How do I correctly ensure they have the same size?

I thought this might be the answer:

```
    predicted_loes_score = predicted_loes_score_g.detach()[0]
    loss_g = loss_func(
        predicted_loes_score,
        actual_loes_score_g,
    )
```

but then I get this error later:

```
torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 154, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Answer (score 9):

```
predicted_loes_score_g = tensor([[-24.9374]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```

which is size [1,1]

```
actual_loes_score_g = tensor([20.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

which is size [1]

You need to either remove a dimension from your prediction or add a dimension to your target. I would recommend the latter because that extra dimension corresponds to your batch size. Try this:

```
actual_loes_score_g =  actual_loes_score_g.unsqueeze(1)
```